# How many people died in the Legend of Korra?

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

One of the defining qualities of Avatar series is the low mortality rate of the battles in spite of the advanced techniques and weaponry. Of the top of my head, I can cite six deaths.

- Tarrlok and Noatak (suicide with Noatak as casualty)
- Gazhan (suicide)
- P'Li (killed by Suyin deliberately)
- Ming-Hua (killed by Mako, probably due to unintended use of excessive force)
- Earth Queen (killed by Zaheer deliberately)

So, I can only remember six deaths where only three of them are killed in action by their enemies and a mere two of them are killed with the intent of killing, proving my point of low casualty wars.

The question is how many people died in the whole series. I am also looking for names of the casualties as well as how they died when applicable. Unnamed casualties are welcome if their death is confirmed. People died of old age or sickness unrelated to battles are not included.

Comment: Considering it's ostensibly a kids' show, I'd say it has a relatively *high* mortality rate. I was gonna say I'm surprised that they got away with showing some of those deaths, but given the way Nick slowly nerfed the show into the ground, they arguably didn't.

Comment: @F1Krazy Well, the Last Airbender was a kids show. I think the intended audience for Korra is 4-5 years older. Zaheer killing the earth queen is quite a graphic scene considering the method and motivation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, it took me a moment to remember the names.

- Season 2 - Unalaq disintegrated with spirit Vaatu. So I guess that's 2 people.
- Season 3 - Aiwei, Suyin's security guard that was a secret mole for the Red Lotus. His soul is trapped in the Spirit world, so I guess he physically died offscreen.
- Season 4 - Hiroshi Sato, Asami's father, is presumed dead in the final episode. Also, there were 2 watchtower guards that were hit by a laser blast from the giant robot machine. I assume they are also dead.

So I think that's 6 additional people, for a total of twelve.

Comment: I agree with this, except I'd clarify that Vaatu isn't a person, nor did he permanently die. He was purified and power is diminished, but he will return either forcibly pulled out of Rava or naturally splitting out of Rava in a few thousand years; this may result in a reincarnation cycle of a Dark Avatar. (I'm not sure which will happen, or the mechanics of Dark Avatar reincarnation, but I'm certain that the spirit that embodies darkness is not "dead" in the sense of a person dying.)